# Bubble Sort compiling but out of bounds

Tags: java, sorting, bounds

I am having issues with getting a simple bubble sort of an array to work properly.
It compiles, but I'm getting an *out of bounds exception* when running the program.

I know what an out of bounds error is but I can't see why it occurred in this case.

Any geniuses there that know how to fix this? Thank you

```
  public class BubbleSort
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create the array that we want to sort with buble sort alogorithm
        int intArray[] = new int[]{5, 90, 35, 45, 150, 3};

        //print the array before the bubble sort
        System.out.println("Array before Bubble Sort");
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        }

        // sort an array using bubble sort algorithm
        bubbleSort(intArray);
        System.out.println("");

        // print array after sorting using bubble sort
        System.out.println("Array after Bubble Sort");

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(intArray[i] + "");
        }

    }

    private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray)
    {
        int n = intArray.length;
        int hold = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //allows us to pass or loop around array
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) //allows on pass or comparison
            {
                if (intArray[j] > intArray[j + 1]) //swap the elements!
                {
                    hold = intArray[j];
                    intArray[j] = intArray[j + 1];
                    intArray[j + 1] = hold;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented on the lines where you made a mistake

```
public static class BubbleSort { //you need static here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int intArray[] = new int[] { 5, 90, 35, 45, 150, 3 };
        System.out.println("Array before Bubble Sort");
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        }
        bubbleSort(intArray);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Array after Bubble Sort");
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(intArray[i] + " "); // you need space between the parenthesis so that results show up readable
        }
    }

    private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) {
        int n = intArray.length;
        int hold = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++){ // j has to be equal to 0, or your first value in the array won't get compared, and -1 because of the array out of bounds error
                if (intArray[j] > intArray[j + 1]){
                    hold = intArray[j];
                    intArray[j] = intArray[j + 1];
                    intArray[j + 1] = hold;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Your soution fixed it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the outer loop, `i==0`.

Therefore in the inner loop `j` would go from `1` to `n-i-1==n-1`.

When `j==(n-1)`, `intArray[j+1]` would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration of the outer loop of your `bubbleSort` method, when `i` is equal to zero, `j` is allowed to go up to `n-i-1`, inclusive, i.e. the last value of `j` is going to be `n-1`.

When this happens, `inArray[j+1]` will be out of bounds, because it would be equivalent to `inArray[n]`. The last valid index is `n-1`.

to fix this, make sure that the outer loop starts at `i=1` instead of `i=0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 

 public class BubbleSort
 {
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    // create the array that we want to sort with buble sort alogorithm
    int intArray[] = new int[] {5, 90, 35, 45, 150, 3};

    //print the array before the bubble sort
    System.out.println ("Array before Bubble Sort");
      for (int i = 0 ; i  intArray[j+1])  //swap the elements!
        {

        hold = intArray[j];
        intArray[j] = intArray[j + 1];
        intArray[j + 1] = hold;
   }
  }
 }

}

}
```

Replace j < (n-i) with j < (n-i)-1.
**Reason**
In the last iteration, j will have a value equal to one less than the length of the array(ie it points to the last element). But when you compare elements with index j+1, you are pointing to an out of bound element. Thus the exception. Hope it helps.

Comment: Strange. Why is the whole code not being displayed?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Out of bounds error solved.  Looking at the output here... why is 5 still first on the list after bubble sort? Should it not be 3, 5, 35, etc (in ascending order)?

Answer (score 0):

(this is to answer your question about 3 not being the first value displayed)
code should go like this if you want in assenting order
you have missed for( int j=0; j<(n-i-1); j++

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) //loop trough array
        {
           for( int j=0; j<(n-i-1); j++) //loop allows variable j pass on for comparison
           {
               if ( intArray[j]> intArray[j+1]) // if current slot in array j is bigger than the next one
```